# Wordpress Site Speed (Maybe Server Issue)

Tags: performance, server

Okay so I have a newly created eCommerce site here at work, and I have set up W3 Total Cache with MaxCDN running. It all works correctly, all the static content is run from there without any problems.

However, my main problem is the website as a whole is still incredibly slow. Using Chrome Dev tools and watching the Network Timeline I can clearly see that when you load any page of the website, there is a request to the server and it spends roughly 5 seconds just "waiting" before any content begins to load.

So I've come to the conclusion that the content is pretty well optimised but there seems to be some issue with the speed at which it gets the initial request from the server....

Can anyone shed some light on what the issue might be, or any potential fixes when consider the slow speeds due to "waiting" for the server?

[image]

Comment: share the site url

Comment: Open your CLI and `tracert 0.0.0.0`, where the number is your servers IP address or your hostname/domain. On Mac/Linux you can use `traceroute` instead. Please [edit] your question with that info.

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything:

- A slow and un-optimized MySQL server
- A theme not suited for big databases
- A faulty plugin combination
- ...

You can make sure that it's not a plugin or theme issue by disabling all plugins and using a built in theme (I like Twenty Twelve).

What else you can do to find the bottle neck:

- Use XDebug
- Use the MySQL Profiler plugin